# Delete all future recurring event from iPhone calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Can any one having idea how to delete recurring event from iPhone calendar?

I am using this code for store event which is repeat every week.

```
EKEventStore *eventSotre = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventSotre];


EKRecurrenceRule *recurrenceRule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyWeekly interval:1 end:nil];
[event addRecurrenceRule:recurrenceRule];

[event setCalendar:[eventSotre defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

event.title= @"EventTitle";
NSDate *duedate = [NSDate date];
event.startDate =duedate;
event.endDate= duedate;

NSArray *arrAlarm = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:duedate]];
event.alarms= arrAlarm;

NSError *err;
BOOL isSuceess=[eventSotre saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

strIdentifier = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", event.eventIdentifier];;

if(isSuceess){
    UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event" message:@"Event added in calendar" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"       otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertview show];
}
else{
    UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event" message:[err description] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertview show];
}
```

Now I want  to delete all future events from the iPhone calendar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got Solution my self.

For delete all future events I am using this code

```
EKEventStore* store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init] ;
EKEvent* eventToRemove = [store eventWithIdentifier:strIdentifier];
if (eventToRemove != nil) {
    NSError* error = nil;
    [store removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanFutureEvents error:&error];
}
```

For Delete current day entry we have to use "EKSpanThisEvent" and for delete future events we have to use "EKSpanFutureEvents"

Comment: EKSpanThisEvent:    Affect this event only.
EKSpanFutureEvents :  Affect this event and all after it.