# Programmatically add custom event in the iPhone Calendar but not deleted it

Tags: objective-c, calendar, ekeventkit

I am programmatically added event to calendar but now i want to delete it from calendar so create event id & use it to remove event from calendar but its not work from me anyone please help me.. here is code which i use to delete event , please help me

```
 EKEventStore *eventstore = [[EKEventStore alloc]init];

 [eventstore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:
  ^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) 
 {
  if (!granted) 
  {
   return ;
   }
   //addEventGranted = 1;
   EKEvent* eventToRemove = [eventstore    eventWithIdentifier:self.savedEventId];
   if (eventToRemove) 
  {
   NSError* error = nil;
  [eventstore removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error];
   }
 }];}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480045/delete-all-future-recurring-event-from-iphone-calendar

Comment: i did same as your link but when i check it in simuloter calendar then nothing is happen all added events are remain as it is no one is deleted can you say why this happen? @kb920

Comment: have you tried "EKSpanFutureEvents" instead of "EKSpanThisEvent"

Comment: yes tried with both "EKSpanFutureEvents" & "EKSpanThisEvent" but no one is deleted @kb920